# Layout issue with absolute positioned div

Tags: javascript, html, css, positioning, css-position

I have a parent/child divs coded as;

```
<div class="classes scrollable">
<div class="items">
....Some content
</div>
</div>
```

My CSS is;

```
.scrollable {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.scrollable .items {
    clear: both;
    position: absolute;
    width: 20000em;
}
```

Actually my "items" div has it's "left" position changed dynamically via JS (for kind of carousel effect...scrolls to left/right)

Also bcoz it is an absolute div, I cannot get the parent div "scrollable" to expand as per "items" content.

How do I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `height` on the `.scrollable`. The inner scrolling div is just one row, right?

Answer (score 1):

What keeps you from not making `.items` absolutely positioned?
Can't you just use something like `margin-left: -100px`, instead of  `left: -100px;`?

Working example of what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/fk5Q2/